# Error on tomcat netbeans org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, netbeans

I keep receiving error from Tomcat logs as follows

````
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkResourceClassFields(IntrospectionModeller.java:204)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:137)```
````

Comment: Error tells it well, you need JPA api jar, and probably an impl.

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using? What jars did you package in the application? What version of Java are you running on?

Comment: It worked now. I deleted all depedencies and rebuilt my app. Thanks a lot!!!